# React Image-crop showing error as it is not uploading the image in the proper form and is getting an error from the backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am get an error while uploading a cropped image using `react-image-crop`. I think, I am not properly converting the base64 to file type before uploading or that function isn't running?. I am new to react and javascript so lots of things, still confuses me. Can anyone please have a look at the code and help resolve the issue?

I am using django rest api.

This is the link to the package:

```
https://github.com/DominicTobias/react-image-crop
```

This is the error I am getting  from the backend while uploading.

```
{profile_pic: ["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]}
profile_pic: ["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]
```

This is the code.

```
function getResizedCanvas(canvas, newWidth, newHeight) {
  const tmpCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  tmpCanvas.width = newWidth;
  tmpCanvas.height = newHeight;

  const ctx = tmpCanvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(
    canvas,
    0,
    0,
    canvas.width,
    canvas.height,
    0,
    0,
    newWidth,
    newHeight
  );

  return tmpCanvas;
}


export default function ProfilePicEdit() {

    const [{user}, dispatch] = useStateValue()

    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

    const [upImg, setUpImg] = useState();
    // const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const imgRef = useRef(null);
    const previewCanvasRef = useRef(null);
    const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ unit: "%", width: 30, aspect: 1 / 1 });
    const [completedCrop, setCompletedCrop] = useState(null);
    
    const classes = useStyles();

    const onSelectFile = (e) => {
        if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("load", () => setUpImg(reader.result));
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        // setImage(
        //   {image: e.target.files[0]}
        //   )
        }
    };

    const onLoad = useCallback((img) => {
        imgRef.current = img;
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!completedCrop || !previewCanvasRef.current || !imgRef.current) {
        return;
        }

        const image = imgRef.current;
        const canvas = previewCanvasRef.current;
        const crop = completedCrop;

        const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
        const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        canvas.width = crop.width * pixelRatio;
        canvas.height = crop.height * pixelRatio;

        ctx.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0, 0, pixelRatio, 0, 0);
        ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = "high";

        ctx.drawImage(
        image,
        crop.x * scaleX,
        crop.y * scaleY,
        crop.width * scaleX,
        crop.height * scaleY,
        0,
        0,
        crop.width,
        crop.height
        );

    const reader = new FileReader()
    canvas.toBlob(blob => {
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            dataURLtoFile(reader.result, `sample.jpg`)
        }
    })

    const dataURLtoFile = (dataurl, filename) => {
        let arr = dataurl.split(','),
        mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]), 
        n = bstr.length, 
        u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
                
        while(n--){
            u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
        }
        let croppedImage = new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
        setUpImg({upImg: croppedImage }) 
    }

    }, [completedCrop]);


    const onSubmit = () => {
        let formData = new FormData();

        // console.log(upImg)
        formData.append('profile_pic', upImg);

        axiosInstance.put('api/profile/update/', formData)
        // window.location.reload();
    }


    return (
    <div className="imagecropper">
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
                <label htmlFor="profile-pic">
                    <input
                    accept="image/*"
                    className={classes.input}
                    id="profile-pic"
                    onChange={onSelectFile}
                    name="image"
                    type="file"
                    ref={register}
                />                  {console.log(upImg)}
                    <div className="profile_pic__edit_main">
                        {upImg === undefined ? 
                            <Avatar src={user && user.profile_pic} alt={user && user.username}
                                className="profile__pic_edit"
                            />
                            : <Avatar src={upImg} className="profile__pic_edit" alt="" />
                        }
                        <div className="profile_pic__edit_icon">
                            <IconButton color="primary" component="span">
                                <PhotoCamera fontSize="large" />
                            </IconButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </label>   
            </Grid>      
                <ReactCrop
                    src={upImg}
                    onImageLoaded={onLoad}
                    crop={crop}
                    onChange={(c) => setCrop(c)}
                    onComplete={(c) => setCompletedCrop(c)}
                />
            {/* <div>
                <canvas
                ref={previewCanvasRef}
                // Rounding is important so the canvas width and height matches/is a multiple for sharpness.
                style={{
                    width: Math.round(completedCrop?.width ?? 0),
                    height: Math.round(completedCrop?.height ?? 0)
                }}
                />
            </div> */}

            <Button
                type="submit"
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.submit}
            >
                Update
            </Button>
    </form>
    </div>
  );

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried loading the image using the onload event instead of useEffect?
I don't know for sure what's the real problem here, but you may have some loading issues. I've worked with canvas recently and ran into some problems regarding image loading (it's asyncronous).
Try moving the canvas drawing action into the image load event OR verify if the image ref is not null inside useEffect before drawing it into the canvas.

Comment: Yeah. okay I will check that out. The problem is it seems the image is not getting converted back to blob after the cropping function.

Comment: I checked the image ref and it is still showing null inside useEffect. Can you tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: Hey, can you create a codepen?
Perhaps useEffect is not getting triggered by the changes made to useRef
This article might help you with the useRef() issue:
https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780

Comment: I am not sure how to do it though. I will give it a try. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no need to use **useEffect and useCallback** in this code.
ReactCrop is giving you onComplete so the only thing you need to do is to start drawing after that.

### api error:

in the above code you are sending base64 string to the api but as we can see in error api except for **File format**.
also **setting name to blob** is necessary to recognize as File.

i collect these changes and this code should be working:

```js
export default function ProfilePicEdit() {
  const [upImg, setUpImg] = useState();
  const imgRef = useRef(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ unit: "%", width: 30, aspect: 1 / 1 });
  const croppedImage = useRef(null);

  const onSelectFile = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener("load", () => setUpImg(reader.result));
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const onLoad = (img) => {
    imgRef.current = img;
  };

  const onCropComplete = (crop) => {
    makeClientCrop(crop);
  };

  const makeClientCrop = async (crop) => {
    if (imgRef.current && crop.width && crop.height) {
      croppedImage.current = await getCroppedImg(
        imgRef.current,
        crop,
        "newFile.jpeg"
      );
    }
  };

  const getCroppedImg = (image, crop, fileName) => {
    if (!canvasRef.current || !imgRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
    const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = crop.width * pixelRatio;
    canvas.height = crop.height * pixelRatio;

    ctx.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0, 0, pixelRatio, 0, 0);
    ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = "high";
    ctx.drawImage(
      image,
      crop.x * scaleX,
      crop.y * scaleY,
      crop.width * scaleX,
      crop.height * scaleY,
      0,
      0,
      crop.width,
      crop.height
    );

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
        if (!blob) {
          //reject(new Error('Canvas is empty'));
          console.error("Canvas is empty");
          return;
        }
        blob.name = fileName;
        resolve(blob);
      }, "image/jpeg");
    });
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("profile_pic", croppedImage.current,
      croppedImage.current.name);

    axiosInstance.put('api/profile/update/', formData)
    window.location.reload();
  };

  return (
    <div className="imagecropper">
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="profile-pic">
            <input
              accept="image/*"
              id="profile-pic"
              onChange={onSelectFile}
              name="image"
              type="file"
            />
            <div className="profile_pic__edit_main">
              <img
                style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}
                src={upImg}
                className="profile__pic_edit"
                alt=""
              />
            </div>
          </label>
        </div>
        <ReactCrop
          src={upImg}
          onImageLoaded={onLoad}
          crop={crop}
          onChange={(c) => setCrop(c)}
          onComplete={onCropComplete}
        />
        <div>
          <canvas
            ref={canvasRef}
          />
        </div>
            <Button
                type="submit"
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.submit}
            >
                Update
            </Button>
    </form>
    </div>
  );

}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response, but I am still getting the same error when  I ran the code.
I consoled out `upImg` and it is still in base64.

Comment: @Danny Answer edited. i was appending upImg instead of croppedImage.current to formData. you can see result in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bartik-dpl19?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your time...I  tried this in my code connecting to api, I am getting this error now, `{profile_pic: [,…]} profile_pic: [,…] 0: "File extension '' is not allowed. Allowed extensions are: 'bmp, dib, gif, tif, tiff, jfif, jpe, jpg, jpeg, pbm,etc..'"`

Comment: @Danny looks like file name lost when we append to formData. according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63230458/django-rest-framework-doesnt-accept-blob-picture-file-file-extension-is-not) i edit this answer.

Comment: Can you tell me what it means, like a bit more detail? or about how to make changes to resolve this? thanks :)

Comment: i added a third parameter to formData append and its file name with name.validextention format . if you console.log(croppendImage.current) you see a blob with name but if you console.log(formData.get('profile_pic')) after appending of course you see a File without name. thats because we need to specify the file name with third parameter of formData.append. you can check this on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bartik-dpl19?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: It works, perfectly, now I need to look through the code and learn how you did. Thanks a lot again! :)